# How to edit data in cell of datatable primefaces 3.4.2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My project use primefaces ver 3.4.2. I don't see that version supporting cell editing in datatable as showcased [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf). 
3.4.2 has row editing that has many action to edit data in datatable. I cannot upgrade the primefaces library version. How can I achieve cell editing in 3.4.2?

Comment: Cell editing is available in [3.4.2](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4). Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

try this : editable="true" and editMode="cell" which will allow us to edit cell.. (this is supported in 3.4.2) and columns must be written as below ..

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" editable="true"
 editMode="cell" widgetVar="carsTable">

    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onCellEdit}" update=":form:messages" /> 

       <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:25%">  
           <p:cellEditor>  
               <f:facet name="output">
                  <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
               </f:facet>  
               <f:facet name="input">
                  <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.model}" style="width:96%"/>
               </f:facet>  
           </p:cellEditor>  
       </p:column> 

</p:datatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              <p:column headerText="#{tdBundle['Tdkt_VoteEmp.agreeNum.label']}">
                            <!--<p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{unit.agreeNum1}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <h:inputText value="#{unit.agreeNum1}" />
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>-->
                            <p:inplace id="basic">  
                                <p:inputText value="#{unit.agreeNum1}"/>  
                            </p:inplace> 
                        </p:column>
```

That is my code. When agreeNum1 has no data. I cannot click in that cell to input data.

Comment: why you use <p:inplace inside <p:column.. ?? any specific reason??

Comment: Because datatable in pf 3.4.2 don't support editMode="cell", just support row edit. I see input or edit data by editMode="cell" is very fast, i think my customer like that too.