# How to add Cell Edit by click or edit single column in Datatable using Primefaces 3.4.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using Primefaces 3.4.2 and due to some restrictions i can't update it to latest version. I have to add a edit option for column "Contact" in the datatable in below code so that user can edit it and update it.

I already tried by using Primefaces inplace and row editing (only for a single column)  but it takes ages to submit when clicked on save or cancel button.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <p:dialog id="viewSitesHistoricAlarm" header="Alarm Information" widgetVar="viewSiteHistoricAlmDialog" modal="false" minWidth="930" 
        minHeight="600" fixedCenter="false" appendToBody="true" effect="FADE" effectDuration="0.5" close="true" closeListener="#{historicActivity.dlgClose}">

        <h:form id="viewsiteHistoricAlmFrm">
          <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin:5px;" id="printid">
                 <p:dataTable id="alarmResolution"  var="alm" value="#{historicActivity.alarmResolution}" 
                            style="border-right-width: 2px !important;overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: auto; width:895px;max-height:500px !important;" paginatorPosition="top" paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}
                            {NextPageLink}" editable="true" rows="100" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">
                            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{historicActivity.updateContactName}" />
                                <p:column style="width:155px">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Action Time"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{alm.timeActioned}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column >
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="User"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{alm.user}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column style="width:140px" >
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Action"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{alm.action}"/>
                                </p:column>


  <p:column style="width:140px" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Contact"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{alm.alm.contactName}"/>
                            </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Comments"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{alm.comments}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                 <p:column headerText="Modify">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                 </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                            <p:toolbar>
                                <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
                                <p:commandButton value="CSV" ajax="false" style="color:#A8A6A8!important;">
                                        <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="alarmResolution" fileName="historicalarminfo" preProcessor="#{exporter.preProcessor}" postProcessor="#{exporter.postProcessor}"/>
                                    </p:commandButton>
                                    <p:commandButton value="PDF"  style="color:#A8A6A8!important;" update="viewsiteHistoricAlmFrm" onstart= "pdfDownloadDialog.show();"  rendered="#{historicActivity.val==true}">
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pdfExp.columnValues}" value="#{historicActivity.exptrColValsAlmSpecific}"/>  
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pdfExp.tabColumnsWithSize}" value="#{historicActivity.exptrSpecificAlmCol}"/>   
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pdfExp.headerContent}" value="#{historicActivity.exptrHeaderAlmSpecific}"/>               
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pdfExp.logo}" value="#{historicActivity.exptrHeaderLogo}"/> 
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pdfExp.pageTitle}" value="#{historicActivity.exptrPgTitle}"/> 
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pdfExp.fileName}" value="#{historicActivity.exptrFileName}"/>
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pdfExp.redirectTo}" value="HistoricActivityPage?faces-redirect=true"/>            
                                     </p:commandButton>
                                      <p:commandButton value="PDF"  style="color:#A8A6A8!important;"  actionListener
    ="#{historicActivity.checkHistoricSiteAlmsSize}"  update="viewsiteHistoricAlmFrm" rendered
    ="#{historicActivity.val==false}"/>
                                    <p:commandButton value="XLS" ajax="false" style="color:#A8A6A8!important;">
                                        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="alarmResolution"  preProcessor="#{exporter.preProcessor}" postProcessor="#{exporter.postProcessor}" fileName="historicalarminfo"/>
                                    </p:commandButton>
                                </p:toolbarGroup>
                            </p:toolbar>
                         </h:panelGrid>                                
        </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
        </ui:composition>
```

Comment: You have `h:outputText` on your contact row and you want to edit thus there will be an `h:inputText` right to it OR you want `h:outputText` to be replaced by `h:inputText` once edit is clicked ?

Comment: @YouYou i tried that but the issue is i guess may be due to the old version of Primefaces library it takes ages to submit when clicked on save or cancel button and can't achieve ajax behavior as well.

Comment: So why don't you upgrade ?

Comment: Because you must have an `h:inputText` bounded by `h:form` to submit a value (ajaxly or not) to server

Comment: @YouYou Due to some limitations i can't. Have figure out some solution keeping the old version.

Comment: Have a look on that answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760557/1460591

Comment: @YouYou as the OP said in that link. Primefaces 3.4.2 doesn't support  "editMode". I have checked in the documentation as well.

Comment: i don't understand the problem: you like edit column contact when you edit the table?